# Error in add Kotlin activity to Java based project

Tags: java, android, android-activity, kotlin

When I put my first Kotlin base activity in my project in Android Studio, on compile I faced with this error:

> Error:java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort:
>   socket write error

By removing it from the project error is disappeared. I add Kotlin activity using New->Activity then I chosen Kotlin as language and not did more anything.
My android studio version is 3.0.1.

My Kotlin compiling setting is adding below:

[image]

Anyone knows what's the problem or how can I fix it?

Comment: can you post more information about your error?

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it by cleaning the cache and restart settings:

File-> Invalidate Caches/Restart